# panel unit root versus individual unit root

Tags: panel-data, stationarity, unit-root

If panel unit root tests show that a particular variable is stationary, can one safely ignore the the individual per-panel ADF tests that show majority of them do have unit roots?

There was a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/256634/common-unit-root-or-individual-unit-root) three years ago but with no answer.